# Angular 2 multiple TemplateRef

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a custom datagrid that can display data either as cards or the more tradional table/list/grid. I can do it pretty easily if I do not want the templates to be customizable as shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1jCI91y0sKCMQfpi9iXZ)

Here I have a `my-grid` component that gets passed the data to be rendered. Then I loop over the data and render the `card-view` or `list-view` component depending on the desired view which is controlled by the `view toggle` (code in `app/my-grid.ts` file)

I want to provide the ability to pass in custom templates and I am thinking something like this:

```
<my-grid>
  <card-view-template>
    <template var-item>
      <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
      {{item.home}}
    </template>
  </card-view-template>
  <list-view-template>
    <template var-item>
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      {{item.home}}
    </template>
  </card-view-template>
</my-grid>
```

How can I get to what I want from where I am at?

Comment: You might have a look at the source of other structural directives like `*ngFor`. I had a brief look but don't have a working example of a custom implementation myself yet.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve my issue as shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3LXXXwDmx4D8zu09gz4)

```
import {Component, Directive, ContentChild, TemplateRef} from 'angular2/core';

    @Directive({
        selector: 'card-view'
    })
    export class CardViewComponent {
      @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTmpl;

      ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log('In CCV', this.itemTmpl)
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps anyone else that is facing a similar problem. Or maybe someone can point me to a better solution

*Update*:
For the newer versions of ng2 (RC at the point of writing this), you will need to use `forwardRef()` in some cases like so:

`@ContentChild(forwardRef(() => CardViewComponent)) cardViewComponent;
@ContentChild(forwardRef(() => ListViewComponent)) listViewComponent;`

Comment: It does still work for me, both in beta and RC. The only difference in RC being that you need to use forwardRef(). Updated the answer